How comment package is supposed to work?
I am playing with the package comment.
I read the doc (not very detailed, but ok).
But I am not able to understand why the following MWE is not compiling:
\documentclass{article} 
   \usepackage{comment}

\begin{document} 
    I would like to hide something.

    \begin{comment}
        this will not appear
    \end{comment}  

    This text will be shown.
\end{document}

What did I miss ?

The documentation is pretty explicit (emphasis mine):

The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it.

The indentations before \begin{comment} and end{comment} are not allowed.

space is ok before the begin part

Perhaps mention can one could just use \NewDocumentEnvironment{comment}{+b}{}{}, it should do the same thing without the limit.

Strange but OK.

@daleif yes, it worth mentioning it. I found it simpler indeed.

@R.N Well, it's not really strange, it has to do with how the package is implemented. In fact, as @daleif points out the bit about no spaces before is a white lie: it is strictly true only for \end{comment}.

@R.N not too strange, the comment package was made in a different time
